# Observing "Slave went offline during the build" and Job fails

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, continuous-integration, virtual-machine

I am using AWS Instance as a Jenkin Master and a VM as a slave which is creating a instance and executing some test on that created Instance.

I am facing "Slave went offline during the build" frequently.

```
Slave went offline during the build
ERROR: Connection was broken: java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:50)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2335)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2804)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:802)
```

I tried the following options which didn't fixed the issue.

- Updated the Node configuration from Jenkins > Manage Jenkins >
  Manage Nodes > Configure by disabling Free disk space and Free temp
  space
- Updated the node Availablity as "Take this slave as online when in
  demand and off-line when Idle" and specified the demand delay as 1
  and idle delay as 2

After that also am facing the same Issue.

Updated the idle delay to 10 and its started some what working but some time soon after the job started I faced this slave went offline during build issue.

Somebody please clarify me the root cause of this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find the fix for this? I am facing the same issue and opened a jira ticket https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-19145